# Query on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I´m new to Python and I'm trying to get a subset of rows/columns from a DataFrame:

```
In [1]:
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [2]:
example=DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,5),columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

In [3]:
example.a={2,4,6,8,10,12}

In [4]:
example

Out[4]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   2   0.225608 0.023888 0.535053 0.953350 
1   4   0.803721 0.741708 0.256522 0.062574 
2   6   0.354936 0.597274 0.801495 0.763515 
3   8   0.204974 0.870951 0.220088 0.446273 
4   10  0.673855 0.693210 0.494213 0.842049 
5   12  0.516609 0.038669 0.972165 0.183945 

In [5]:
example[['a','b','d','e']].query('a==10')

Out[5]:
    a   b   d   e
4   10  0.673855 0.494213 0.842049 

In [6]:
example[['b','d','e']].query('a==10')

.....

UndefinedVariableError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The 1st case was ok, but I got error on the 2nd query, do you know why is this error showing up? thank you very much

Comment: in `example[['b','d','e']]` you only have a subset of `example` that doesn't include column `a`

Comment: Thank you, I´ve included a and now it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `example[['b','d','e']]` you only have a subset of `example` that doesn't include column `a`.

To get values `['b','d','e']` from the row where `a==10` you just need to turn the query and index around. So first it queries, returning only the row, and then on that row you use your index:

```
In[113]: example.query('a==10')[['b','c','d']]
Out[113]: 
          b         c         d
4  0.439672  0.181699  0.770421
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the second selection `example[['b','d','e']]`, you effectively drop 'a' from the dataframe:

```
example[['b','d','e']]
b   d   e
0   0.910757    0.565006    0.284420
1   0.601034    0.697879    0.983803
2   0.516938    0.829621    0.471825
3   0.896217    0.663177    0.093502
4   0.277488    0.796543    0.643166
5   0.594420    0.759634    0.164800
```

So you're trying to access a column that doesn't exist. In other words, if you want to query a column from a dataframe, you need to include it in your selection before querying it.